# Warning for dangling connection in IDE?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, intellij-idea, ide

Is there any IDE, like Eclipse or Intellij that support warnings about dangling connections.
For example:

```
Connection conn = null;
if (conn != null) {
     try {
         Statement createStatement = conn.createStatement();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         // Accidentally forgot to close conn. 
     }
}
```

Is there an option to get such an warning in any language? NetBeans seems like it doesn't have such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ has inspections for unclosed JDBC resources (*Settings/Editor/Inspections/JDBC resource opened but not safely closed*).

[image: Inspection]

Comment: Great. Thank you on an answer and lovely provided image!